# Activity by length

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, interval

I was having a hard time finding out how to make this any faster. I broke down the code that I am playing with into more methods than necessary to try and see where things could increase. Can anyone think of any good ideas?  I am not opposed to using different data structures.

The main idea is receiving an Activity with start and finish time, they are sorted by length, and we are adding them with that greedy style of algo.

Here are the proceeding methods, that I am struggling with.

```
private void findSolutionUsingGreedyByLength_FAST() {

    /** sort the list of activities based on the length of each activity */
    Collections.sort(activityList, new LengthComparator());

    /** initialize the list of selected activites to be empty */
    solution = new ArrayList<Activity>();
    ArrayList<Activity> solutionList = (ArrayList<Activity>) solution;
    /** alias for the solution Collection */

    Activity nextActivity = null;

    /**
     * Scan through all the activities, from shortest to longest, adding
     * each one to the solution, if it does not conflict with an already
     * scheduled activity
     */
    for (int i = 0; i < activityList.size(); i++) {

        nextActivity = activityList.get(i);

        solutionList = iterate(nextActivity, solutionList);

    }

    solution = solutionList;

}

private ArrayList<Activity> iterate(Activity nextActivity,
        ArrayList<Activity> solutionList) {

    boolean conflict = false;

    /**
     * Scan all the activites already placed in the schedule, to see if the
     * new activity conflicts with any already selected activities
     */
    for (Activity someActivity : solutionList) {

        if (conflict = conflict(someActivity, nextActivity)) {
            break;
        }

    }

    if (!conflict) {
        solutionList.add(nextActivity);
    }

    return solutionList;

}

private boolean conflict(Activity someActivity, Activity nextActivity) {

    boolean conflict = false;

    /** check for overlapping activities */

    if (!((someActivity.getFinishTime() <= nextActivity.getStartTime()) || (nextActivity
            .getFinishTime() <= someActivity.getStartTime()))) {
        conflict = true;

        // break;

    }

    return conflict;

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? 

From what I see here you're trying to get a new list containing as many non-conflicting activities as possible. Is that right?

Comment: yes that would be correct, and the sort that occurs on the selection is in order of length, too which I cannot change.

Comment: The stated problem still lacks description. Let's say in total there are only three activities A (duration 5 minutes) and B (duration 10 minutes), and C (duration 15 minutes). A is in conflict with both B and C, but B and C are not in conflict with each other. What will be the acceptable answer? Only A (one activity with duration 5 minutes) or B and C (two activities with duration 25 minutes)?

Comment: A, a came first. But to be honest they all would, because the time cap is 40000 so it goes through a lot of choices.

Answer (score 3):

For speed: ignore the length, sort by start time, and if the start time of the current task is before the end time of the previous task, skip it.

If you need the sort-by-length idea, then review the if-statement in `conflict()`, it doesn't handle cases where an activity's end time is before its own start time.

Consider using joda-time or java8 in order to get robust classes which provide the concept of an interval, including overlap-checking.

Comment: I appreciate that , is there anything else you see, this was for a class , my teacher is a dinosaur so we aren't allowed to change anything else. Thank you for the insite though .

Comment: Also I appreciate the link to code review, I realize I should have posted there.

Answer (score 2):

This answer will look more at your coding style and the code itself, not so much on performance issues.

```
private void findSolutionUsingGreedyByLength_FAST() {
```

Judging by what you actually do in the method, I would expect this method to input a `List<Activity> activityList` and return `List<Activity>`. At the moment, your method is dependent on several class variables and is therefore causing side effects, things that cannot be seen by checking the method header only.

So change your method to:

```
private List<Activity> findSolutionUsingGreedyByLength_FAST(List<Activity> activityList) {
```

---

You don't need to typecast `solution` here, and `solutionList = solution` will have no effect as that's only an object reference. The list itself is the same. If you do `solution.add(...)` or `solutionList.add(...)` it will have the same effect.

```
    /** initialize the list of selected activites to be empty */
    solution = new ArrayList<Activity>();
    ArrayList<Activity> solutionList = (ArrayList<Activity>) solution;
    /** alias for the solution Collection */
```

Also, use `List<Activity>` for declaration, and instantiate with `ArrayList<Activity>`.

---

```
    for (int i = 0; i < activityList.size(); i++) {
```

As you're not using the indexes inside the loop other than to get the activity at that position, you can use an "enchanced for-loop":

```
    for (Activity nextActivity : activityList) {
```

---

Your iterate method returns the same list as is given to it through a parameter, that's not needed. Either create a new list and return that (not recommended in your case), or change it to a `void` method:

```
private void iterate(Activity nextActivity, List<Activity> solutionList) {
```

---

Your iterate method can be written as:

```
private void iterate(Activity nextActivity, List<Activity> solutionList) {
    for (Activity someActivity : solutionList) {
        if (conflict(someActivity, nextActivity)) {
            return;
        }
    }
    solutionList.add(nextActivity);
}
```

---

Your conflict method can also be simplified, as it also doesn't need the temporary `boolean` variable.

```
private boolean conflict(Activity someActivity, Activity nextActivity) {
    /** check for overlapping activities */
    return !((someActivity.getFinishTime() <= nextActivity.getStartTime()) || (nextActivity
            .getFinishTime() <= someActivity.getStartTime()));
}
```

I *really* don't like this condition:

```
!((someActivity.getFinishTime() <= nextActivity.getStartTime()) || (nextActivity
            .getFinishTime() <= someActivity.getStartTime()));
```

Let's read it out loud, shall we?

*"If not someActivity's finish time is less than or equal to nextActivity's start time or nextActivity's finish time is less than or equal to someActivity's starting time"*. There are two words in this sentence that makes it hard to grasp the real condition: One word is **not** and the other is **or**. The fact that you're using more parenthesis than necessary also complicates things.

Let's split it up:

```
boolean activityAFinishesBeforeBStarts = someActivity.getFinishTime() <= nextActivity.getStartTime();
boolean activityBFinishesBeforeAStarts = nextActivity.getFinishTime() <= someActivity.getStartTime();
return !((activityAFinishesBeforeBStarts) || (activityBFinishesBeforeAStarts));
```

We can still make changes to the return statement!

Let's look at the truth table

```
A B  (A || B)   Result
0 0     0         1
1 0     1         0
0 1     1         0
1 1     1         0
```

We can write this as `!A && !B`:

```
return !activityAFinishesBeforeBStarts && !activityBFinishesBeforeAStarts;
```

---

This statement does nothing as `solutionList` is already the same as `solution`:

```
solution = solutionList;
```

I would simply do:

```
return solutionList;
```

Answer (score 1):

**With many more activities than time slots**, most of our time is spent checking for conflicts.  We can ease that out by using a bit set to represent used times:

```
  BitSet roster = new BitSet();
  for ( final Activity activity : activityList ) {
    final int end = roster.nextSetBit(activity.getStartTime());
    // < 0 : no such index
    if ( end < 0 || end >= activity.getFinishTime() ) {
      roster.set(activity.getStartTime(), activity.getFinishTime());
      solution.add(activity);
    }
  }
```

Going through 10 million randomly generated activities took about 4779ms versus the initial 71183ms, sorting included.  You can shave off some more time by giving the roster an initial capacity (like the 40000 you mentioned).

**With many activities and many time slots**, we may need to set up a balanced interval tree.  I'm not sure if this is within the scope of your course.